# Service version for "services.mysql.version" is not defined

Tags: php, magento

I ran the following commands:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition

composer require --dev magento/ece-tools magento/magento-cloud-docker
```

And when I run this:

```
./vendor/bin/ece-docker build:compose
```

I have the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue mostly occurs due to absence of .magento.docker.yml

More Info: https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-installation.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).